# Problem: Sites which flood the user's email account with messages saying:-

Tags: e-commerce, email

- Thank you for buying 'x'
- We are going to deliver 'x' today
- Our van has left the yard
- Our van is in your street
- 'x' has just been left on your doorstep.

Do a fair bit of online shopping and this can become most of your email traffic.

Is there any need to send *any* of this email traffic, if a user has already set up an account on the business's website ?

Comment: Is providing a different method of these notices an option (app notification, text message, ...)? Is there a companion smartphone app for this business? These days, I'm seeing notices like this to be sent more often as ephemeral app notifications that can be seen in passing, rather than emails that typically require user action to sort through.

Comment: App notifications are certainly easier to dismiss than email.

Comment: As Amazon employees seem to given up ringing door bells, the only Amazon email they send which is definitely useful, is the one that tells you your stuff is outside the front door...

Answer (score 0):

Heuristics say that feedback should be provided when:

- Relevant
- Fits importance and urgency
- Comprehensible and meaningful
- Within appropriate context (time and place)

I don't know if there is any research on this. I can say that personally I have never considered relevant status updates for my order to be flood or overwhelming and I find it important to be informed on the go instead of me logging in on the website to find out what the status is.

The store I make most of my purchases will notify me with:
Thank you for buying X it will be delivered on xx/xx
The package was shipped
The shipping will be delivered today between x - x hours

Yet it would be cool to get another notification that the van is in my street so I can make sure I am able to open the door to receive the delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because users aren't going to be constantly checking back on your website just to see when their parcel is going to be delivered.

Some kind of "push" notification - email or text message - will alert the customer.